# Why is .. not resolved before running into MAX_PATH?

Tags: windows, winapi

I just tried publishing a WebAPI Project to my local disk and got a number of errors which all basically read as

`The complete path to 'E:\<MyVeryLongPathToMyService>\some folder\some subfolder\MyService\..\..\..\bin\<more path>\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll' exceeds the maximum number of characters permitted by the file system.`

This turned out to be true, since the path above had 261 characters (with the limit being 260 of course).

If the `..` were resolved beforehand, the path would have been shorter and I would not have hit the limit. Why is directory traversal not resolved earlier to prevent this from happening?

Comment: It just isn't. The system doesn't do that for you. You could do it. Or you could use APIs that support long paths.

Comment: The runtime library has to first convert the file path to a native NT path, for which it does have to resolve "." and ".." components, but prior to Windows 10 long path support, it uses a stack-allocated, `MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR)` buffer when it calls `RtlGetFullPathName_Ustr`, the native implementation of `GetFullPathName`. This builds the resolved path directly in the target buffer. It doesn't even try, however, if the buffer isn't big enough to hold the maximum possible path length for the given path. You'll have to resolve it yourself, and prefix with "\\?\" if it's too long.

Comment: @eryksun This should be an actual answer.

Comment: @eryksun If you write that up as an answer I can accept it. Does the prefix  "\\?\" only work on Win10 (and future versions) then?

Comment: prefix \\?\ work even on xp- with this you can use paths up to 32767 (if use unicode api)

Comment: @vonludi this is all documented, a bit of research would go along way